# What can I do for keeping the track for a vectors elements?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, matrix, vector

I read matrices from an input with `ifstream`. Then, I take those matrices' `[0][0]`<sup>th</sup> element and put it in a `vector` and sort (descending).

My question is, when I sort the elements, I lose track of the matrix number of those elements. I need it; I have to give an output to show the c<sup>th</sup> matrix is the sum of the a<sup>th</sup> and the b<sup>th</sup> matrices.

After I sort them, I cannot find which matrix is which.

```
for(int r=0;r<(matrixColumn*matrixRow);r++) {
    for(int x=0;x<matrixColumn;x++) {
        for(int y=0;y<matrixRow;y++) {
            for(int u=0;u<matrixNumber;u++) {
                temp.push_back(totalmat[u][x][y]);
            }
            for(int v = 1; v < temp.size(); v++){
                key = temp[v];
                for(w = v - 1; (w >= 0) && (temp[w] < key); w--) {
                    temp[w+1] = temp[w];
                }
                temp[w+1] = key;
            }
```

Here, I take the elements, put it in a vector and sort them by decending order.

```
bool IfkIsTwo(vector<int> temp, int &q,int &f,int &z)
{
    int a=temp.size()-1;
    int b=temp.size()-2;
    for(int c=0;c<temp.size()-2;c++) {
        for(int d=1;d<temp.size()-2;d++) {
            while(b!=c) {
                if(temp[a]+temp[b]==temp[c])
                    return true;
                else
                    b--;   
            }
            a=temp.size()-d-1;
            b=temp.size()-d-2;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is my function that adds up the elements. It looks if there is any element that is sum of the 2 elements. I need to know which is sum of which 2 two elements by the first irregular order of elements.

For example:

If the initial order is like:

```
3 2 5 7 1 4
```

And I sort those like:

```
7 5 4 3 2 1
```

And find that sum of 2 and 5 gives 7, it have to give me `The matrix 3 is sum of the matrices 1 and 2` (It begins with 0)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `std::vector<int>`, you can store a `std::vector<`[`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair)`<int, int>>` where the first value in the pair is the value of that index and the second value is the index itself (calculated by `row*(num_cols)+ col`).

When you're sorting, you'll just need to look at the value at that index like:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> temp;
if(temp.at(some_spot).first < temp.at(other_spot).first) { ...
```

Comment: Instead of `std::pair<int,int>`, you can use any kind of class with a `std::vector<T>`. I would prefer a struct with named members over a pair: `struct matrix_info { int index, int value }; std::vector<matrix_info> the_vector;`  Name as appropriate.